# Django Rest Framework make model calculations using pandas or not (seeking efficient way)

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-rest-framework

I am using django_rest_framework for a web application. I have created the necessary API end points for all the necessary CRUD operations for the respective tables.

Now I want to perform calculations on the data of multiple tables and send the calculated result as a Response for the frontend to process.

I could think of two ways of doing this, which would be more efficient (or the correct (the Django way) way to do it, if any):

**1. Calculations using Pandas**

- Create a view which will be called with a GET request
- Get the querysets of data from the necessary tables
- Convert them to pandas DataFrames
- Perform the necessary calculations
- Reconvert the DataFrame to a JSON object and return a Response

***2. Create a Separate Model, Serializer and View for the Calculations***

If there is some other library or method that can do this, please provide some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to retrieve the objects as dataframe:

```
queryset = Costs_workspaces.objects.all()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(queryset.values())
```

Another example with a viewset:

```
class apiname(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = your_model.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.get_queryset().values())

        ... more code ...

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(your dict), content_type="application/json")
```

Last option that you can us is [Django-pandas](https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/)

Comment: Yes the solution suggested by you is basically the option 1 that I am using, my question was regarding the more optimal way of doing this. It was weather to use Pandas to do the calculations (which also involves converting and reconverting from DataFrames) or if using database logic and creating a separate MVT (model, serializer, View) for the calculations required for data in DB